# Why does K3B (KDE disc burning program) always asks to install additional packages when it starts?

Tags: linux, kde, packages, k3b

Every time that I start [K3B](http://www.k3b.org/) I get a prompt that asks me to install additional packages, specifically some mp3 codecs.

This seems strange, because once I have installed them once they should be available forever, not just for the current session; but, after a better check, I discovered that this is not the case, because my K3B can perfectly handle MP3 even without installing the packages: it seems that it asks me to install packages that are already present.

What's the reason of this odd behaviour, and how can I do to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in k3b, either click on the `Don't show again` (if shown) or go to `System Settings > Application and System Notifications > Other Notifications > Restricted Codec Availability` and turn it off there.